# Signup on reactjs using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

so i was trying to make a signup & login features on my web. My problem here is i cant post signup data to my api.
Here is the code that i make :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { API_URL } from '../utils/constant';
import axios from 'axios';
import swal from 'sweetalert';


export default class Signup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
        };
      }

      handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password,
        };

        axios
        .post(API_URL + "signup", data)
        .then(res => {
          swal({
            tittle: "sukses",
            text: "sukses",
            icon: "success",
            button: false,
          })
        }
      ).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
      };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="signup">
                <Container>

            <div className="signup-page">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username anda" class="form-control" onChange={e=> this.username = e.target.value}  />
                        <div class="form-text"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" onChange={e=> this.password = e.target.value}/>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
                </form>
                </div>
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My code here is not giving me any error, but the data is not post/added to my API.
i hope there is any suggestion from anyone of you because im just new into this reactjs,

this is my github link so maybe you might check it :
https://github.com/dannyambarita/Tubes_PWL/

Comment: After `const data`, if you console.log(data) do the values exist?

Comment: i tried that, and i checked the console, and there's nothing in there.

Comment: ow, my bad, actually there's the data, i was adding console log in wrong place

Comment: Does your server even receive the request? Perhaps the problem is on the backend

Comment: If the URL is correct, the problem is in the server. Have you access to the server? If yes, share the code.

Comment: i try to get the data with axios, and i can get the data from my api. so i think my server receive the request. But i just check status code from network, and its said 500 internal server error, what that suppose to be?

Comment: 500 means internal server error, meaning there's a bug with your server code. Share it and we might help

Comment: Something wrong in server-sice. There is no other way to know, if you don't have access to server-side source code. IF you share the code maybe someone here help you. Is Node.js/Express?

Comment: maybe from github? i add it in my post

Comment: What if you send the `data` as an object? `.post(API_URL + "signup", {data} )`

Comment: Sorry. You should share the application that runs in server-side in localhost:3004.

Comment: Also could you add `API_URL` to your post?